# How can I add labels to my diagram with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, label, sunburst-diagram

I am making an interactive tool for creating Sunburst diagrams like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423) with d3.js, svg and JQuery. The code for drawing the diagram is from that page, with a few minor modifications. I'm trying to draw text labels on the sections of the diagram, but although the elements are showing up in the Web Inspector (Chrome), they aren't visible on screen. I have tried to adapt code from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/910126), and to some extent this has worked (Web Inspector says the elements exist), but I am mystified as to why the elements themselves don't show up. This is my code - the section for drawing labels is near the bottom. I would just use the code from the example page with labels, but the layout is very different and I'd have to start from scratch again.

```
var width = 850,
height = 850,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var svg = d3.select("#vis-wrap")
    .insert("svg", "*")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height * 0.52 + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

var path = svg.datum(data).selectAll("path")
.data(partition.nodes)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; }) // hide inner ring
.attr("d", arc)
.style("stroke", "#fff")
.style("fill", function(d) {return d.color;} )
.style("fill-rule", "evenodd")
.each(stash);

// Problem here
path.insert("text", "*")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x + d.dx / 2 - Math.PI / 2) / Math.PI * 180 + ")"; })
    .attr("x", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y); })
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

d3.selectAll("input[name=mode]").on("change", function change() {
    var value = this.value === "count"
        ? function() { return 1; }
        : function(d) { return d.size; };

    path.data(partition.value(value).nodes)
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween);
  });


// Stash the old values for transition.
function stash(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.dx0 = d.dx;
}

// Interpolate the arcs in data space.
function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
  return function(t) {
    var b = i(t);
    a.x0 = b.x;
    a.dx0 = b.dx;
    return arc(b);
  };
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the text a child of the path i.e.

```
<path ...>
   <text>something</text>
</path>
```

I'm afraid that's not valid. You need to make the text element a sibling.

Confusingly you've called the `<g>` element you've created svg but it want's to be a child of that i.e.

svg.insert("text")

rather than path.insert("text")

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a dream! I should probably rename my 'svg' variable though... :)